# how to use mongodb atlas data api

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Aab.png)    let headersList = {

```
 "api-key":
```

"U5H4A6FcMbEuZ33LP0ACQHP0ydkXkGLLJnDfNzQzCXTpzxL8QdJ8tH7NocITeZvv",
"Content-Type": "application/json"
}

```
let bodyContent = JSON.stringify({
    "collection":"users",
    "database":"college",
    "dataSource":"Cluster0",
    "projection": {}
});

let reqOptions = {
  url: "  https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-tfdur/endpoint/data/beta/action/findOne",
  method: "POST",
  headers: headersList,
  body: bodyContent,
}

axios.request(reqOptions).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
})

here its giving me the cors error
```

Comment: what did you try? where did you fail? please share your code and error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i edit the question please check and respond

Comment: Have whitelisted the IP in `MongoDB Atlas IP Whitelist tab.`?